# Why php-gd does not work? not BOM, not error code, php-gd enabled

Tags: php, html, php-gd

Any php-gd, for this example:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/gif"); 
$imagen = imagecreate(300,100); 
$bgcolor = imagecolorallocate($imagen,230,230,230);
$negro = imagecolorallocate($imagen,0,0,0);
imagesetpixel($imagen,30,30,$negro);
imageline($imagen,30,80,270,80,$negro);
imagegif($imagen);
imagedestroy($imagen);
?>
```

I have 2 servers, the same file in one of them displayed properly and in another no longer load ...

In both servers phpinfo shows the same data-enabled, and until recently worked in php-gd both. I do not receive any error messages.

[image]

**Any idea? Why it can happen and how to fix it?**

Comment: Try removing the `content-type` and see if it gives you a plain-text error.

Comment: Get binary: GIF87a,d����,..

Comment: Whenever this happened to me, it was either due to error, or some sort of output that has gone unnoticed prior to outputting the image on screen (so here it would be something above imagegif function).